# Dynamic JSP input boxes?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, jsp

How can I create a JSP page with dynamic selection/input boxes?
The first one will show all table names:

```html
<select name="table">
     <option value="" disabled selected>Tabela</option>
     <%  while(rset.next()){ %>
          <option font color="black" value="<%= rset.getString(1)%>">                 <%=rset.getString(1)%>
          </option>
     <% } %>;
     <%TableDAO.closeConnection();%>
</select><br>
```

this part is working good, in the start of the page Im getting rset to have a result set from a search that return table names.

So, I have the first selection box, user will pick the Table in which he wants to add a new entry. When the user picks a table name from that selection box, I want the program to create X input boxes below, being X the number of columns from that table, each one with the column's name as placeholder.

Is this possible? JSP is always processed before display right? how could I do this dynamic part, Js? Could someone give me some samples?

Answer (score 0):

1. Display a page with the first selection box
2. User picks an option
3. User submits the form
4. JSP receives the data
5. Use that data to query the database
6. Use that data to display a **second** page with the next set of inputs on it

---

If you want to avoid loading entire new pages then you'll need to write an API using your JSP (generally speaking, people follow the RESTful pattern and return JSON these days). Then you can use JavaScript to make HTTP requests (i.e. Ajax) to that API.

Comment: Sounds like a plan, if it were something easy (like 3 lines of code I wasn't aware) i would try the other way, but this sounds simple but working.